# Erro Call to undefined function mysqli_num_roms

Tags: php

Está dando um erro

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_num_roms()

Já tentei resolver, mas não consegui.

```
<?php

  require_once '../includes/configuration.php';

  $userName = $_POST["user-name"];
  $userPass = $_POST["user-pass"];

  $SQL = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Usuario, Senha FROM administradores WHERE Usuario='$userName' AND Senha='$userPass' ");

  if (mysqli_num_roms($SQL) != 0){

      echo "logado";

  }else{

      echo "Login incorreto";

  }

?>
```

Comment: nao seria `mysqli_num_rows`? parece um erro de digitação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_num_roms` não existe, em inglês linhas é `rows`, então se quer pegar o numero de linhas use:

```
  if (mysqli_num_rows($SQL) != 0) {
      echo "logado";
  } else {
      echo "Login incorreto";
  }
```

Leia sempre a documentação:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda